c++ 'const' in multi-file
In C++ Primer, it tells me that I should modify all const variables with 'extern'. However, when I tried that in DevC++ 5.11 with C++11, I found that it was not necessary.
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "main3.cpp"

extern const int a;

int main() {
    std::cout<<a;
    return 0;
}

//main3.cpp
#include <iostream>

 const int a = 11;



It will print 11. Why?
Thanks for your help.
When I add extern into main3.cpp, it errors. Why didn't the book's description come up?

Note that DevC++ is an IDE not a compiler. Its use has no bearing in the issue. It does have a bearing in the solution since it determines how you add a separate translation unit to the project.  But you didn't ask for a solution; only for an explanation.

"In C++ Primer, it tells i should modify all const variables with 'extern'": Does it actually do that? I do not see any good reason to do that. You almost never want a const variable to have external linkage. Instead they are usually defined in header files with the default internal linkage.

You should generally post the code that does not work rather then the code that works.

What @user17732522 said.  By leaving it default static, in a header if it needs to be shared, the compiler can replace constants with a literal, whereas when you explicitly create an instance in a separate translation unit, it will necessarily explicitly fetch that constant from memory - potentially a little extra code everywhere it is used.

However I have found a PDF of that and on page 95 it describes this practice for const variables with initialisers that are not constant expressions.  That is not what you are doing here.  If you are looking at a different part of the book, add a reference to the section/page number and perhaps a verbatim quotation.

Thank you for your help, these comments are very useful. I realized the need to systematically understand what happened during the execution of the program. And indeed, C++Primer is too old, I should also learn about the latest C++ instead of just learning everything from it.

Not so much execution as build in this case.  You cannot execute it if it does not successfully build.

@Clifford My book is a translated version, and the quote is as follows: 'If you want to share const objects between multiple files, you must add the extern  keyword before the variable definition.'.

@zzz without complete context, that is rather vague.

const and extern mean different things. You should either (or both) when appropriate. Don't do cargo-cult programming.

By default a const data object at global scope in C++ has internal linkage, so to be visible to a separately compiled and linked translation unit, it must be explicitly declared extern.
The issue here is that you have not separately compiled and linked main3.cpp.  You have used the preprocessor to include main3.cpp in the single main.cpp translation unit.  That is generally bad practice, and hopefully not advised by your reference text.
The conventional form for projects with multiple translation units is to have a declarative header file and separately compiled instantive modules:
//main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "main3.hpp"

int main() 
{
    std::cout<<a;
    return 0;
}

//main3.hpp
#pragma once

// A const without an initialiser is a declaration.
extern const int a;

// main3.cpp

// A const with an initialiser is an instantiation.
extern const int a = 11;

Then main.cpp and the (inappropriately named) main3.cpp must be separately compiled then linked.  In DevC++ you do that by adding both translation units to your project.  Long ago since I used it, but I would guess right-click the project root and "Add file..." or similar.

I got that, maybe I need to know more about complied and linked.

@zzz yes, but you did not ask about that (and did not know to ask perhaps), but presumably C++ Primer discusses that?  If not, I would consider a different reference.  Anyhow I added the information as if you had asked.

I did not know what the key is because I'm a  C++ beginner.Your information is important. I changed my code and got the right results.  Thank you very much!

The use of extern is to declare a variable that is defined somewhere else. extern in main3.cpp doesn't make sense: a is defined in main3.cpp.
The way #include works is basically copy-pasting the contents of one file into the other. extern const int a is not needed here because main3.cpp is included within main.cpp.
To avoid confusion, rename main3.cpp to main3.hpp. .cpp files are seldom included within other .cpp files.

Yes, if I rename main3.cpp to main3.hpp, it works. So when I used main3.cpp, extern const int a means a was defined somewhere else and it was found in main3.cpp.It's legal. But when I add extern to main3.cpp, what caused the error?

@zzz What did the error message say? You never included that in your question.  From the information in your question the result of the inclusion would be equivalent to https://onlinegdb.com/RAFU_LyNc which does not produce an error.  To answer that question it would be necessary for you to post the build log in its entirety,  including the error message.

@zzz  I am guessing that you both included and compiled-and-linked main3.cpp.  That would have caused a linker error for multiple definitions.  Take-home here:  Always include in your question diagnostic messages your toolchain emits if you are asking for a diagnosis.  Even better the full build log so we can see what you are compiling and linking.

@Clifford Yes,that is where my mistake lies. After removing the inclusion, I get the result I anticipated.
